# Java Application connected with MySQL went dead

Tags: java, mysql

[java application connected mysql http://nowstock.co.kr/p11.png](http://nowstock.co.kr/p11.png)

Above program is Java Application connected to MySQL. I can control all the documents of my web site with it. Deleting documents, Creating documents and Saving documents. Anyway, This program was maded followed this tutorial : http://www.javaguicodexample.com/javadesktopguimysql1.html

The problem is, when I delete the 5~10 documents , It is easily deleted with no problem. But the number is over 20, the program went dead. The program stopped. I could't control the program anymore. Maybe I think it is problem of the size of handling datas at once. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

**The problem : I can't delete more than 20 documents at once. when I try this, program went dead**

Comment: First you have to figure out what the problem IS.

Comment: @Gimby I editted. sorry to awkward english. the problem is, I can't delete more than 30 documnets at once.

Comment: Show the code that deletes the records and present some logs. Is it stands now we can all guess for hours what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a million reason for that. You need to profile your program and detect where the bottleneck is.

For example, a common beginner's mistake is not using connection pool, hence for each transaction (delete) a new database connection has to be created -- which is costly.

Other common causes: you did not realize how much memory your code is using. Probably the virtual machine is maxed out and give up.

This could also be troughput / locking problem on MySQL.

I recommend you learn how to profile java & MySQL. There should be plenty article / tutorials about this in internet.