# Java Application connected to MySQL stuck

Tags: java, mysql

[mysql application http://nowstock.co.kr/p11.png](http://nowstock.co.kr/p11.png)

Above program is Java Application connected to MySQL.
I can control all the documents of my web site with it.

**features : Deleting / Creating / Saving documents.**

The problem is, when I delete the 1~10 documents , It is easily deleted with no problem. **But the number is over 20**, the program went dead. I could't control the program anymore. Maybe I think it is problem of the size of handling datas at once.

Source code: part of deleting method

```
  private void deleteButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
  int[] selected = masterTable.getSelectedRows();
  List<documentsviewer.XeDocuments> toRemove = new      ArrayList<documentsviewer.XeDocuments>(selected.length);
    for (int idx = 0; idx < selected.length; idx++) {
        documentsviewer.XeDocuments x = list.get(masterTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selected[idx]));
        toRemove.add(x);
        entityManager.remove(x);
    }
    list.removeAll(toRemove);
}
```

- Full source code ▼
- DocumentViewer.java : http://ideone.com/GIMS8F
- XeDocuments.java : http://ideone.com/O4QKsJ

not long code. please check it and please give me a hint... I couldn't sleep last night because of this problem... help me..

Comment: I see that you asked the same question and already accepted an answer from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547998/java-application-connected-with-mysql-went-dead/21548785#21548785

Comment: @onepotato not same... this question have more information than previous question. I think people doesn't understand my awkward english so I add more information...

Comment: Where does this "went dead" happen? In your list.get(masterTable…) or in entityManager.remove()?

Comment: @DirkLachowski remove()... over 30 line, program go dead.